# Red Hat vNIC(Virtual NIC) association to physical NIC

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface

I have a virtual network interface named bond0.700 connected to a vlan (ID 700), and 6 physical NIC (eth0 to 5) on RHEL 5.5.

**Hint :**

```
[root@rhle ~]$ cd /sys/devices/virtual/net
[root@rhle net]$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 0 Mar  7 13:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 0 Mar  7 13:58 ..    
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 0 Mar  7 13:58 bond0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 0 Mar  7 13:58 bond0.700
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 0 Mar  7 13:58 lo
```

I know vNIC IP address, netmask, gateway.

I don't know how vNIC is attached to real network interface (physical ones); is it associated with only one NIC or multiple NIC or all of them?

**Question ?**

**"How to know which physical NIC (one or more/all) attached to the vNIC bond0.700"**

**Update**

Output of `ls -l /proc/net/bonding/`

```
[root@rhle ~]$ cd /proc/net/bonding/

[root@rhle bonding]$ ll

-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  8 08:38 bond0
```

**Thanks in Advance**

**Response(Update)**

in `/proc/net/vlan` there is two files "bond0.700" and "config" file the config file contain this structure:

```
VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
bond0.700      | 700  | bond0
```

Where Type_RAW is the physical device which the Vlan attached to,there can be more devices since you can added them by "vconfig"

Comment: Please provide some specifics, as your question is unclear. As just one example, is "bond0.700" another name for "vNIC", or are these supposed to be different? What is it you're really trying to understand?

Comment: no the only name for vNIC is bond0.700

Comment: Have a look at the output of `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0.700`. It should provide all the information you need.

Comment: It dosen't exist here the output :                                                                   [root@rhle  ~]$ cd /proc/net/bonding/
[root@rhle bonding]$ ls -al 
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  8 08:38 bond0